# INCORRECT SUM() OUTPUT on LEFT JOIN CASE QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i select the specific table and use the case method to get only the max value of 8 there is no problem with it.

but when i use the 1st query and join it to get the SUM value of totalhrs it gave me different value

[REFERENCE TABLE WORKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIUIs.png)

```
SELECT l1.userid,(l2.fname+' '+l2.lname) as empname,l2.department,l1.date,MIN(l1.time_in) as timein,MAX(l1.time_in) as timeout,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,MIN(l1.time_in)) ,CONVERT(datetime,MAX(l1.time_in)))/60.0 > 8 THEN 8 ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,MIN(l1.time_in)) ,CONVERT(datetime,MAX(l1.time_in)))/60.0 END    as totalhrs
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,'08:00',MIN(l1.time_in)) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,'08:00',MIN(l1.time_in)) ELSE 0 END as late,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,MAX(l1.time_in),'17:00') > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,MAX(l1.time_in),'17:00') ELSE 0 END as undertime,MAX(image_in) as imgo,MIN(image_in) as imgi 
                             from  hgs_hr_attendancelogs l1 
                             LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid,lname,fname,department from user_acc)l2 
                             ON l1.userid = l2.userid 
                             WHERE l1.userid  = '442' and l1.date between '2021-03-16' and '2021-03-31' 
                             group by   l1.userid,l1.date,l2.fname,l2.lname,l2.department 
                             ORDER BY l1.userid
```

[OUTPUT IN SUM INSTEAD ADD THE 4th column(THE SUM IS **78**) it gives **2668.17**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqjVw.png)

```
SELECT l1.userid,SUM(l2.totalhrs),COUNT(l2.late)
FROM hgs_hr_attendancelogs l1
LEFT JOIN(SELECT l1.userid,(l2.fname+' '+l2.lname) as empname,l2.department,l1.date,MIN(l1.time_in) as timein,MAX(l1.time_in) as timeout,
CAST(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,MIN(l1.time_in)) ,CONVERT(datetime,MAX(l1.time_in)))/60.0 > 8 THEN 8 ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,MIN(l1.time_in)) ,CONVERT(datetime,MAX(l1.time_in)))/60.0 END as DECIMAL(18,2)) totalhrs
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,'08:00',MIN(l1.time_in)) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,'08:00',MIN(l1.time_in)) ELSE 0 END as late,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,MAX(l1.time_in),'17:00') > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,MAX(l1.time_in),'17:00') ELSE 0 END as undertime,MAX(image_in) as imgo,MIN(image_in) as imgi 
                             from  hgs_hr_attendancelogs l1 
                             LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid,lname,fname,department from user_acc)l2 
                             ON l1.userid = l2.userid 
                             group by   l1.userid,l1.date,l2.fname,l2.lname,l2.department ) l2
ON l1.userid = l2.userid
WHERE  l2.date between '2021-03-16' and '2021-03-31'
GROUP BY l1.userid
```

Comment: You seem to have included a lot of irrelevant code in your question. Perhaps if you managed to reduce your question to a [minimal reproducible error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you would find more assistance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results are much, much, much more helpful than simply saying "not working".  A clear explanation of the logic you want to implement also helps others understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for my question. thankyou for advising. I will do it to my future post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you dont need the second join hgs_hr_attendancelogs (in not working query). A query like below should work. please check.

```
select
    t1.userid, SUM(t1.totalhrs),COUNT(t1.late)
from
    (
        --working
        SELECT 
          l1.userid,(l2.fname+' '+l2.lname) as empname,l2.department,l1.date,MIN(l1.time_in) as timein,MAX(l1.time_in) as timeout,
          CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,MIN(l1.time_in)) ,CONVERT(datetime,MAX(l1.time_in)))/60.0 > 8 
              THEN 8 
             ELSE 
              DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,MIN(l1.time_in)) ,CONVERT(datetime,MAX(l1.time_in)))/60.0 
          END as totalhrs,
          CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,'08:00',MIN(l1.time_in)) > 0 
              THEN DATEDIFF(minute,'08:00',MIN(l1.time_in)) 
             ELSE 
              0 
          END as late,
          CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,MAX(l1.time_in),'17:00') > 0 
              THEN DATEDIFF(minute,MAX(l1.time_in),'17:00') 
            ELSE 
              0 
          END as undertime,
          MAX(image_in) as imgo,
          MIN(image_in) as imgi
        from  
          hgs_hr_attendancelogs l1 
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid,lname,fname,department from user_acc)l2 ON l1.userid = l2.userid 
        WHERE 
          l1.userid  = '442' 
          and l1.date between '2021-03-16' and '2021-03-31' 
        group by   
          l1.userid,l1.date,l2.fname,l2.lname,l2.department 
    ) t1
group by
    l1.userid
ORDER BY 
    l1.userid
```

And reg the 'query not working', did you try moving the `l2.date between '2021-03-16' and '2021-03-31'` inside the left join?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i overlooked this solution.
atleast its working now.

i just edit the last four line and make COUNT(t1.late) to SUM(t1.late)